# Grid - no space between columns

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, grid

I defined some UserControl for ListBox

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="deliveriesListBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" DataContext="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="deliveriesListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" xmlns:src="clr-namespace:App"  Margin="0,5">
                            <src:DItem />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>    
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                    
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

UserControl is

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.DItem"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0,5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="Hello" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0">
                                        <Run Text="OK" />

        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" Text="this is working only here.." HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

"WYSIWYG" editor in VS2010 or Expression Blend 4 shows me  space between "this is working only here" and "OK". Picture here - http://xrep.eu/pic.jpg

and thats what i want but.. In emulator and the phone looks like http://xrep.eu/emu.jpg

so, between "this is working only here" and "OK", there is no space.
Can somebody help and tell me how to define, the "OK" string will be at most in right side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="Hello" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" />

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock  FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                                    <Run Text="OK" />

        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" Text="this is working only here.." HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the width of the parent control.

In Design Mode the following code (in the definition of the UserControl) is being executed:

```
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
```

this specifies the height and, more importantly, the width of the the control. This is wide enough so you can see the space between the two pieces of text.

At run time this is being ignored so that the `Grid` (and `UserControl`) takes the width of the items being displayed.

You have two options.

1. Put in some explicit spacing using the `Margin` or `Padding` properties.
2. Set the `HorizontalAlignment` of the `Grid` to `Stretch`.

You will probably have to do some experimentation and tweaking to get exactly the effect you desire.